# How can I find $h(y)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Given the following function 
$$ f(t) =  \begin{cases}
t &\text{for }t\leq2\,,\\
2 &\text{for } t\geq 2\,,\\
\end{cases}
$$
and  $$h'(y)=f(y)\,,$$
how can I find $h(y)$ ?

Comment: You need to integrate $f(t)$

Comment: How can I do it in this case?

Comment: Do it case by case: $\int t \ \mathrm dt=\frac12 t^2+c$ for $t\le 2$ and $\int 2 \ \mathrm dt=2t+c$ for $t \ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

An antiderivative is not unique.  So $c=h(0)$ gives
$$h(y)-h(0)=\int_0^yf(t)dt=\int_0^ytdt =y^2/2$$
for $y\le 2$, so
$$h(y)=y^2/2+c$$
when $y\le 2$.  But if $y>2$, 
$$h(y)-h(2)=\int_2^yf(t)dt=\int_2^y2dt=2(y-2).$$
Id est,
$$h(y)=h(2)+2t-4=(2^2/2+c)+2y-4=2y-2+c$$
when $y>2$.  (You should check btw that $h$ is differentiable, and it is.)